# Como selecionar todas as variáveis do data.frame de uma vez para uma regressão?

Tags: r, regressão, data.frame, lm

Suponha o seguinte `data.frame`:

```
set.seed(1)    
dados <- data.frame(y=rnorm(100), x1=rnorm(100), x2=rnorm(100), x3=rnorm(100), x4=rnorm(100))
```

Se eu quiser rodar uma regressão de y contra `x1`...`xn`, eu posso fazer da seguinte forma:

```
modelo <- lm(y~x1+x2+x3+x4, data=dados)
```

Nesse caso como só tem 4 variáveis, não é exaustivo descrever todas. Mas supondo que fossem 100 variáveis, isto é, de `x1` até `x100`. Como selecionar todas de uma maneira fácil para a regressão?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O operador `.` neste contexto (argumento `formula` da função `lm`) significa "todas as outras colunas que não estão na fórmula".

Dessa forma a regressão de y contra todas as outras colunas do `data.frame` pode ser obtido da seguinte forma:

```
modelo <- lm(y~., data=dados)
```

Referência: `?formula`

Answer (score 2):

O ponto é particularmente útil quando se quer colocar efeitos de interação. Por exemplo, suponhamos que você queira testar um modelo com todas as variáveis e todas as interações de até 2 variáveis, como poderia ser feito?

```
## Conjunto de dados de exemplo
exemplo = data.frame(x1 = 1:3, x2 = 1:3, x3 = 1:3, x4 = 1:3)

## Modelos com todas interações até 2
lm(data = x, formula = x1 ~ (.)^2)

## Modelos com todas as interações até 3
lm(data = x, formula = x1 ~ (.)^3)
```

Answer (score 1):

ou, se `dados` é o seu frame e a primeira coluna tem nome `y` (como é o seu caso),

```
    modelo <- lm(formula=dados)
```

também funciona.